# Making unique identifier in Python

Tags: python, unique

I made a simple program with ten ovals. I will work with them later and I'll need to move ovals, so I need unique name for every oval. However, there is a lot of ovals so I don't want to make every oval on new line of code. I used loop, but then I am not able to make unique name for them. Like for example:

- self.oval_id1 = self.canvas.create_oval(40,40,60,60)
- self.oval_id2 = self.canvas.create_oval(60,40,80,60)...etc

Is there any way to make such names in loop please?

```
import tkinter
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()
        x, y = 50, 50
        for i in range(10):
            self.canvas.create_oval(x-10,y-10,x+10,y+10)
            x += 30
main = Main()
```

Comment: Just build a string out of your loop-index (or in some more crazy setups; your question is broad here; use [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html?highlight=uuid)'s).

Comment: Store the oval identifiers in a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `setattr`:

So, something like:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()
        x, y = 50, 50
        for i in range(10):
            oval = self.canvas.create_oval(x-10,y-10,x+10,y+10)
            setattr(self, 'oval_%d' % i, oval)
            x += 30
```

Comment: This is too complicated, when you can simply store the identifiers in a list or dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Even if tricks could allow you to achieve that, you do not want that. It you need it to be iterable, use an iterable container first, here a list.

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.oval_id = []
        x, y = 50, 50
        for i in range(10):
            self.oval_id.append(self.canvas.create_oval(x-10,y-10,x+10,y+10))
            x += 30
```

You can now use `self.oval_id[i]` to access the i-th oval

Comment: Or even a dictionary if you want to give things descriptive names